# NDCG as scoring function with GridSearchCV and stratified data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm working on a learning to rank task, dataset has a column `thread_id` which is a *group* label (stratified data).
In the evaluation phase I must take into account these groups as my scoring function works on a per-thread fashion (e.g. [nDCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain)).

Now, if I implement nDCG with a signature `scorer(estimator, X, y)` I can easily pass it to [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) as scoring function as in the example below:

```
def my_nDCG(estimator, X, y):
    # group by X['thread_id']
    # compute the result
    return result

splitter = GroupShuffleSplit(...).split(X, groups=X['thread_id'])
cv = GridSearchCV(clf, cv=splitter, scoring=my_nDCG)
```

[GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) selects the model by calling `my_nDCG()`. 
Unfortunately, inside `my_nDCG`, X doesn't have the `thread_id` column as it must be dropped beforehand passing X to `fit()`, otherwise I'd train the model using `thread_id` as feature.

```
cv.fit(X.drop('best_answer', axis=1), y)
```

How can I do this without the *terrible* workaround of keeping  `thread_id` apart as `global` and merging it with X inside `my_nDCG()`?

Is there any other way to use [nDCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain) with scikit-learn? I see scikit supports stratified data but when it comes to model evaluation with stratified data it seems missing proper support.

### Edit

Just noticed [GridSearchCV.fit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.fit) accepts a `groups` parameter, in my case it'd still be `X['thread_id']`.
At this point I only need to read that param within my custom scoring function. How to do it?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? Why is `thread_id` dropped? How is this important for the given metrics? Why cant you just store `thread_id` locally and utilize it if necessary by indexing with the train test indices provided by the splitter?

Comment: I've rewritten the question. Yes, storing thread_id and use it inside the scoring function seems feasible. @Grr

Comment: @w00dy did you figure out how to pass thread_id to scoring function? Can you please share any examples if you did?

Comment: Hey @sam sorry I couldn't find back that project :( Don't remember how I did solve it, probably by storing thread_id as a global object?!